# javah not found error on jdk1.6 but not on jdk1.7

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

If I run

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javah.exe" HelloWorld
```

I get

```
error: cannot access HelloWorld
```

but with

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\javah.exe" HelloWorld
```

the HelloWorld.h is generated

What's wrong? I have the 1.7 on the PATH, in case it were related...

```
class HelloWorld {
 private native void print();
}
```

Comment: javah - is that the file-name?

Comment: Javah is a is a C header and stub file generator

Comment: just to make sure have you physically checked the bin directory of each jdk instellation?

Comment: There is nothing noted in the documentation re: changes 6 -> 7 but common sense would suggest that 7 either adds `.` to or looks in the current directory when a CLASSPATH environment variable isn't set or specified explicitly.

Comment: Is the `HelloWorld` class on the classpath?  Just being in the same directory is not enough.  Try setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or using the `-classpath` flag.

Comment: What I am wondering is if maybe there is something in the jdk6 version thats referencing the version of java found on your path. if you went inside the bin directory of your jdk6 and ran the javah command would it still error?

Comment: Sorry guys for the delay, @JohnKane Yes, physically checked

Comment: @Brian / Eric i've tried both with -classpath ., it doesn't change anything. I'll try running it directly on the folder and let you know.

Comment: ok tested @JohnKane, same result. I ran it on jdk1.7_13 and jdk1.7_15 and worked, but not on jdk1.6_24

Comment: Have you tried replacing the jdk on your path to the java6 version to test if that is the issue?

Comment: @John yes, that's not the issue.

Comment: Did it work when you set the java6 jdk on your path instead of java7 and you ran javah from the location of your java6 jdk?

Comment: @JohnKane Nope, it never worked.

Comment: Are the permissions the same in your java6 jdk directory?

Comment: Do you have a valid class file? I just ran it with no issue using java6

Comment: Hum... after seeing your comment I recompiled the class file and indeed now works. I checked if I had compiled with 7 and javah'd with 6, but no, different behaviour. So I couldn't reproduce the problem. Thanks for your comments! I guess the problem was with the class file indeed.

Comment: Either I close/delete the question, either you put the 'valid class' as an answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that java7 would work with a .java file as input, but java6 seems to need the .class file.  Changing the value of -classpath from src to bin fixed the problem for me.

I.e., when my files look like:

```
src/pkg/Hello.java
bin/pkg/Hello.class
```

I can do any of these:

```
$JAVA_6/javah -classpath -jni -d . -classpath bin pkg.Hello
$JAVA_7/javah -classpath -jni -d . -classpath bin pkg.Hello
$JAVA_7/javah -classpath -jni -d . -classpath src pkg.Hello
```

But not this:

```
$JAVA_6/javah -classpath -jni -d . -classpath src pkg.Hello
```

I'm using openjdk on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to duplicate this when compiling under java6.  Maybe uou compiled your class file with java7 and the Javah packaged with your java6 Jdk cannot read it.